# Javascript version of PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, json, glob

Hi would like to as if there's a way that there's a version of this code to javascript?..

```
<?php 
    $files = glob("texts/*.txt");
    $output = "texts/result.txt";

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        file_put_contents($output, $content, FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

this code will get all .txt file on a folder then convert all of the convert to json...

is it possible?.. and how?..

thank you

Comment: By JavaScript you mean node.js or in a browser? Because if it's the browser option, JavaScript can't access server-side files directly.

Comment: I don't have knowledge on node.js.. but i think this is what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends**

If you're running Javascript in the browser, you can't do this because javascript doesn't typically have access to the file system, so it can't find, read, or write to files on the hard drive.

However, if you're using javascript in a native or server-side infrastructure (such as nodejs), you can add `require('fs');` to your code, and then use the `fs` library (using [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options) to get a list of files instead of PHP's glob, [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) instead of file_get_contents, and [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) instead of file_put_contents),

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. If you are trying to run javascript as a program on your computer, then yes, you'll need to install nodejs on your personal machine.  If you are trying to run this code on a server, then you'll need to install nodejs on the server.

Comment: can i use it on wamp or merge it to php and javascript coding.. sorry if i have a lot of question.. this is my first time will try node.js

Answer (score 0):

Use node.js to run javascripts in the server side.